# Best way to cache currency translation rates in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My shopping app needs to do currency conversion, my plan is to use a crontab to grab the latest exchange rates once an hour. My question is whats the best way to store and use this in my CI application. Should I:
- Write it to the DB everytime its run and then grab the rate from the DB evrytime i need to do a conversion
- Do the same but with a text file
- Write it to a constant in the index.php
- Some sort of core or hook file

Whats the most efficient way

Comment: The problem is a page may have 20 prices on, I'd ideally like to grab the rate once per session and the base the conversions on this rate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick & dirty way would be writing a PHP file with the said currencies. You can use [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to save them safely.

Config:

```
$file = '/path/to/currencies.php';
```

Cronjob:

```
// get data from API (note: you should use proper functions via CURL)
$currencies = file_get_contents('http://some.api.com/currencies');
// decode data
$currencies = json_decode( currencies );
// export data into PHP format
$currencies = var_export( currencies, true );
// save to file
file_put_contents($file, "<?php\r\n $currencies=".$currencies."; \r\n?>");
```

Currency Page:

```
// ensure you get a default something
$currencies = array();
// load data file (note, we use include so we can load it whenever we want)
@include $file;
// output something from array
echo $currencies['EUR'];
```

Note that we don't even connect to DB anywhere, making this very fast. There is also no parsing/conversion. With the DB concept, you have to at least loop over the database rows. Using a normal config medium, such as ini, json or xml files would requiring some form of parsing after PHP loads. Whereas, with this method, it is a part of PHP's loading process; you're just including a small PHP file.

Comment: Agree - it's basically static data - just reading, no real need for the database. Saving to DB and writing to cache once an hour is fine though, but why? Either way, you definitely want it written to a file and not looked up from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common way (which is also efficient) is to have a currencies table in the database.

- Each currency & rate has its own row.
- Based on the chosen locale, grab the appropriate currency info from the database on each page request.
- Wrap your price displays in a function that performs the currency conversion (simple multiplication of the base currency).

Comment: Efficient? Would you bet your head on it?

Comment: Assuming you cache properly, yes.

Comment: Wait, so the DB isn't being used as the cache? ;)

Comment: A database most certainly could be used as a cache store for some objects.  That's not to say it would be the best in this exact situation, but realistically, the impact of a single query per session to fetch rate information from the db is minimal unless you are developing for a high-traffic website.